# Scroll panel to top most of the screen when expanded

Tags: angular-material

I have the following example.  When I expand the panel, the remaining items below it goes down to make room for the content of the opened panel.

[image]
However, what I need is, when I expand the panel, it should scroll upwards so the header of the opened panel is on top.  Reason being is that, I am planning to make the content height to occupy as much height as possibly available in the screen, making the opened panel almost occupy most of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For [Angular Material Component's Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples),

you can use the following `css` for making the expanded expansion-panel to be present above all, 
ie the expanded expansion panel will move to the first position in the list.

`--------- styles.css ---------`.

```
.mat-expansion-panel,
.mat-accordion {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mat-expansion-panel.mat-expanded {
  order: -1;
}
```

**Approach :**

- Give `.mat-accordion`, `display: flex` and manipulate `order` property on the `expanded expansion-panel` to achieve the goal.

**[Stackblitz- Demo showing expaned panel moving to top in the list](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-expanded-moves-to-top?file=styles.scss)**

Comment: Your solution is good.  However, it could be confusing since I know that the panel that i expanded is on the, for example, 3rd row, suddenly it's on the 1st row.  I think I need it to just move to the top without losing the order

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev order here means `flex-box css property`, so it doesnot change the order in the DOM, its just showing that particular div in that specified order. You can see in the DOM structure that the opened expansion panel remains at its position in the DOM.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand.  But your solution is good, another option.  But it's still not what I intend to do.

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev Sorry, i thought this is what you wanted, so implemented a demo for the same.If possible, please create a small demo over stackblitz and there i can try to fix the solution.

Comment: I think the images are not clear.  Assume that those images currently have scroll bars shown.  In the first image, the first 2 collapsed panels are on top.  On the second image, the 2 collapsed panels are well on top almost not shown (but you can still see the small part from the 2nd collapsed panel)